# Difficulty Handling XML Version of the United States Code

Tags: xml, ebook, kindle, epub, xml-schema-validation

So I've been trying to put the United States Code (offered [here](http://uscode.house.gov/download/download.shtml) from the U.S. House of Representatives) so that I can hopefully get it to a point where I can put it into an ebook format (either ePub or for Kindle). The page also provides for the schema, but no matter what I do, it always seems to have issues opening up the document. Any ideas on getting this to be accessible in a format that preserves the hierarchy?

The error I get is:

> The XML file usc26.xml cannot be opened because there is no available
>   data view (XSLT).

It also gives me a line (3) and column (308) for the location of the problem.

Comment: What program(s) are you opening the XML with?

Comment: I've tried using a couple, such as Word, TextWrangler, & Atom. I don't know if it's the size of the document (I'm trying to download Title 26... the Internal Revenue Code). At this point, I thought opening it in Word might be the best way to convert the document to an ePub (because of all the tables and hierarchies), but I get a "The XML file usc26.xml cannot be opened because there is no available data view (XSLT), & then it gives me a line (3) and column (308) for the location of the problem. So I'm wondering if there is an issue with the css file reference. (Terribly sorry for noobishness.)

Comment: Please put that error text directly into your question.

Comment: I was able to open usc26.xml just fine in a Text Editor. It's about 50MB uncompressed, which shouldn't tax most computers at all. Have you tried Notepad? Have you tried downloading a new copy? Also, you do know what XML is, right? It's a markup language and only if you have an accompanying stylesheet will it be friendly to human eyes. XML is about getting information in a consistent manner between different programs.

Comment: So at this point, would I be better off just teaching myself the syntax of stylesheets (which is CSS, correct)? Because for some reason, it seems like that is where the hick-up in all of this is occurring.

Comment: Or I guess, the problem is with the file actually finding the style sheet. So I should be able to direct it to a local file up in the header, correct?